# Lazy load routes in Angularjs with $ocLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, angularjs-routing

I'm using [Angular-ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/) for routing and [oclazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) to load each controllers base on routes (lazy loading).

**Problem:** My `route.js` file is getting bigger and bigger (8000 line until now!)

I lazy load my routes like controllers as below.

```
// app.config(routes.js) ↓

$stateProvider
.state('app.warehouses', {
    url: '/warehouses',
    views: {
        "appContent@app": {
            templateUrl: 'warehouses/warehouses.html',
            controller: 'warehousesCtrl'
     },
     resolve: {
        loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', ($ocLazyLoad) => {
           return $ocLazyLoad.load({
              files: [
                 'warehouses/warehousesRoute.js', // lazy load routes
                 'warehouses/warehousesCtrl.js'
              ]
           });
        }]
     },
})


// warehousesRoute.js ↓

$stateProvider
.state('app.warehouses.warehouse', {
    url: '/warehouse/:id',
    views: {
        "appContent@app": {
            templateUrl: 'warehouses/warehouse.html',
            controller: 'warehouseCtrl'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        loadCtrl: ['$ocLazyLoad', ($ocLazyLoad) => {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('warehouses/warehouse/warehouseCtrl.js');
        }]
    }
})
```

Every thing work fine before refresh app in child views.

**That means:**

When I go to child route `(app.warehouses.warehouse/:id)` by clicking on link, work fine, But when I refresh page in child route `(warehouse/:id)`, I go to **404 Not Found** page!

How Can I solve this Problem?